# How to give an error message when deleting a foreign key constraint in symfony?

Tags: symfony

I have a library system with student, books and library staff. Now a student id(pk) is assigned to a book and/or library staff entity. So if the user clicks delete and that id is associated with to a book and/or library staff entity then the user gets an error. I have tried the try catch syntax but i'm suppose to find another way besides that to use. I have not tried anything else as I'm not sure how to begin this syntax. Is there another way to accomplish such?

```
 public function deleteAction(Request $request, $studentid)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($studentid);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('comtwclagripayrollBundle:student')->find($studentid);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find student entity.');
        }

        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();

    }


    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('student'));
}
```

Just have this at the moment but it gives this error: 
 SQLSTATE[23000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint.

**UPDATE**

```
public function findBystudent($studentbookId, $bookId, $staffId){
    return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
              'select p from comtwclagripayrollBundle:student p
                    where p.studentbookId = :studentbookId AND p.bookId= :bookId or bookId = :studentbookId AND p.staffId= :staffId
                    ')
            ->setParameter('student',$studentId)
            ->setParameter('bookId',$bookId)        
            ->setParameter('staffId',$staffId)  
            ->getResults();

}

 public function deleteAction(Request $request, $studentId)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($studentId);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:student')->findByStudent();

        if ($entity) {
            $this->addFlash('error','ERROR! You cannot delete this Student');
        }

        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
         $this->addFlash('error','Student Deleted');
    }


    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('student'));
}
```

I have created this custom repository, that if it finds this entity then it wouldn't be deleted. But it doesn't work.

Comment: What are your other references? You need to remove from them as well.

Comment: no other references, an error message should be outputted, should not be able to remove it

Comment: your question is misleading. Title says how to delete FK constraint, but here you say it shouldn't be removed.http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php might give you ideas. You need to use try/catch any errors to avoid server returning 500 status.

Comment: ok sorry about the misleading title, I have changed it. Besides using a try/catch, is there another method just to throw this error message

Comment: Hi Andrew I have updated the question and to what I'm currently doing. Could you tell me if this is achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your delete action before deleting Student you can check if you have Books or Libraries associated with him and only delete if none of them are present.

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $studentId)
{
...
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $deletable = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:student')->isDeletable($studentId);

    if (!$deletable) {
        $this->addFlash('error','ERROR! You cannot delete this Student');
    } else {
        $student = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:student')->findByStudentId($studentId);
        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
        $this->addFlash('error','Student Deleted');
    }
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('student'));
}
```

Comment: @terricebrown Quit duplicate posting.

Comment: Hey@svgrafov is it possible to assist me with a question